# How to halve the value in a column based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to implement the following business logic: For a threshold value of 4 for the column `gap`, for the first instance of an ID, when the gap exceeds this threshold, I want to halve the points. Not just that, but the subsequent transactions for that ID should be updated accordingly. e.g. see index 2 and 3 in table B below. The difference of 1000 points (which are new points) should be added to the new_points as long as the gap in the following transaction is <= 4. Else, if the following transaction gap too is more than 4, 1000 points should be added and the result should again be halved. And so on...

Please help.

**Table A**

```
  ID  trn_amt  month_of_trn  gap old_points
0  A      100             0  0.0 1000
1  A      140             3  3.0 2000
2  A      210             9  6.0 3000
3  A      320            10  1.0 4000
4  A      580            13  3.0 5000
5  B      101             0  0.0 6000
6  B      120             2  2.0 7000
7  B      300             8  6.0 8000
8  B      200            10  2.0 9000
```

**Table B**

```
  ID  trn_amt  month_of_trn  gap old_points new_points
0  A      100             0  0.0 1000       1000
1  A      140             3  3.0 2000       2000
2  A      210             9  6.0 3000       3000/2 = 1500
3  A      320            10  1.0 4000       1500 + 1000 = 2500
4  A      580            13  3.0 5000       2500 + 1000 = 3500
5  B      101             0  0.0 6000       6000
6  B      120             2  2.0 7000       7000
7  B      300             8  6.0 8000       8000/2 = 4000
8  B      200            10  2.0 9000       4000 + 1000 = 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not think of a good vectorized solution for this problem, so there may be scope for improvement. One way to tackle this problem is to build the logic using iteration for each group, and keep track of previous point value and current point value as you go.

Given:

```
  ID  trn_amt  month_of_trn  gap  old_points
0  A      100             0  0.0  1000
1  A      140             3  3.0  2000
2  A      210             9  6.0  3000
3  A      320            10  1.0  4000
4  A      580            13  3.0  5000
5  B      101             0  0.0  6000
6  B      120             2  2.0  7000
7  B      300             8  6.0  8000
8  B      200            10  2.0  9000
```

Copying it, and then using pd.read_clipboard allows us to load the df.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')
```

Then, just build a function that does your work

```
def custom_transform(df):
    gaps = df['gap']
    old_points = df['old_points']
    is_gap_big = False #boolean turns True when gap is big enough (>4)
    zipped = zip(gaps, old_points)
    _, prev_point = next(zipped)
    new_points = [prev_point]
    #This loop essentially has access to prev_point, gap, and point. The value for point changes based on conditionals.
    for gap, point in zipped:
        if is_gap_big:
            point = prev_point + 1000
        if gap > 4:
            is_gap_big = True
            point = point // 2 #i am assuming you want ints, and floor operations are fine
        new_points.append(point)
        prev_point = point
    df['new_points'] = new_points
    return df
```

And apply to the dataframe

```
out = df.groupby('ID').apply(custom_transform)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
  ID  trn_amt  month_of_trn  gap  old_points  new_points
0  A      100             0  0.0        1000        1000
1  A      140             3  3.0        2000        2000
2  A      210             9  6.0        3000        1500
3  A      320            10  1.0        4000        2500
4  A      580            13  3.0        5000        3500
5  B      101             0  0.0        6000        6000
6  B      120             2  2.0        7000        7000
7  B      300             8  6.0        8000        4000
8  B      200            10  2.0        9000        5000
```